# Why does Gson serialize a LinkedListMultimap map view as null?

Tags: java, gson, guava

See the below code:

```java
Multimap<String, String> linkedListMap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
Multimap<String, String> linkedHashMap = LinkedHashMultimap.create();
Map<String, String> normalMap = new HashMap<>();

linkedListMap.put("foo", "bar");
linkedHashMap.put("foo2", "bar2");
normalMap.put("fjf", "fsfsj");

System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(linkedListMap.asMap()));
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(linkedHashMap.asMap()));
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(normalMap));
```

It gives the following output:

```
null
{"foo2":["bar2"]}
{"fjf":"fsfsj"}
```

Why can the result of `asMap` on a `LinkedHashMap` be serialized by Gson without any issue, but the result of `asMap` on a `LinkedListMap` always serializes as null?

Comment: It works for me on Gson 2.2.4 and guava 15. Prints `{"foo":["bar"]}`. It doesn't work for Guava r09.

Comment: Ah, updating to Guava 15.0 fixes the problem indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem that existed on Guava 14.0.1.  Updating to Guava 15.0 solved the issue.  I still don't know the cause.